# Delphi load name/value pair from text file

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, tstringlist

Want to load name value pairs into a TStringList.

have a text file with data:

```
a=ant
a=animal
b=bob
d=darn
```

Function to load it:

```
LoadData(argPath: string): TStringList;
var
  data: TStringList;
begin
  data := TStringList.Create(true);
  data.Delimiter := '=';
  try
    data.LoadFromFile(argPath);
  except on E : Exception do
  begin
    Application.MessageBox(PWideChar(E.Message), 
       'Unable to Load Data', MB_OK or MB_ICONERROR);
    Application.Terminate;
  end;
  end;
  Result := data;
end;
```

Result is currently:

```
a=ant
a=animal
b=bob
d=darn
```

want the Result's strings to be:

```
ant
animal
bob
darn
```

and the Result's TObjects to be

```
a
a
b
d
```

After this I want to be able to display this in a TComboBox.

Comment: Will the name be always single char ? Because if so, you could simply store its ordinal value as object (after manual parsing). [not taking into account *weirdness* of this extraordinary requirement...] P.S. the `Delimiter` property has no relation to name value pairs (you might have been looking for `NameValueSeparator`).

Comment: ...which is already `=` by default.

Comment: Using LoadFromFile, Result's strings are going to be the name=value pairs, and Result.Object[x] will all be nil. The string values a, a, b, d are not objects, they're strings, and you don't say what kind of objects they should be. So it's unclear what you're trying to accomplish here. Also, when you say, "I want to be able to display this in a TComboBox" it's unclear what "this" is referring to; the name parts, the value parts, or the name=value strings in their entirety?

Comment: As an aside, the exception you're throwing is odd. The only reasons you'll get an exception are if the file doesn't exist or you run of of memory. A better way to do this is test `FileExists(argPath)` and throw an error or exception saying why if not. Don't wait for the LoadFromFile to fail then throw a meaningless error message. And while this may just be for simple testing, you generally don't want to terminate the app inside of an exception in a method. Let an exception handler in an outer scope handle it, if it exists. If it doesn't, then the application will terminate on its own.

Comment: You've stated what you have and what you'd like to achieve, but you haven't presented a *problem*. What difficulty are you having? You already know about delimiters, strings, and objects; what's preventing you from taking the next step and doing what you want? (As an aside, it's really *not* a good idea to store strings in the `Objects` property. If you want a list of names and values, consider a `TDictionary` instead.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to use the built-in functions in the TStringList. I've broken this down into variables just for ease of reading / understanding, but could be compacted:

```
var
  X: Integer;
  Name, Value: String;
begin
  for X:= 0 to MyList.Count - 1 do begin
    Name:= MyList.Names[X];
    Value:= MyList.ValueFromIndex[X];
    MyCombo.Items.Add(Value);
  end;
end;
```

With that, I'm sure you can figure out the rest (since I'm not sure exactly what you mean by result strings and objects).

Comment: It would be safer and more efficient to use `Value := MyList.ValueFromIndex[X];` instead of `Value := MyList.Values[Name];`.  Then you don't have to worry about duplicate names, which O.O's example clearly shows do exist. The `ValueFromIndex[]` property has been around since Delphi 7.

Comment: @Remy I was working off of how OP intends to use the Name anyway. But yes, that would help with duplicate issues. I actually didn't notice the duplicates until you said something. I naturally skipped the 2 letters in the center, and just read `a..d`. Updated answer.

Comment: @JerryDodge - Basically I want to be able to select "animal" as the combo box's text, but I want the value to be "a."  So a text property and a value property

Comment: I've answered your question as you've asked it. If there's something else you need help with, please feel free to ask a new question. You appear to have been a member here long enough to know how the rules work.

Answer (score 2):

It's preferable to pass the string list as a parameter, to ease lifetime management. It's also better to let the function raise exceptions and deal with them later. That allows more flexibility and the possibility of reuse. Like this:

```
procedure LoadValues(const FileName: string: Values: TStringList);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Values.LoadFromFile(FileName);
  for i := 0 to Values.Count - 1 do
    if Pos(Values.NameValueSeparator, Values[i]) <> 0 then
      Values[i] := Values.ValueFromIndex[i];
end;
```

You cannot store strings directly in the `Objects[]` property of a `TStrings` because strings are managed types. You should probably store the names in a separate string list, or another more capable data structure. It's easy to extend the above code to populate two lists instead of one using the `Names[]` property.

It sounds like you are trying to stuff all of your data into a visual control. Don't do that. Treat visual controls as things to display data and not to hold and manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Gave up on trying to load the combo box with `LoadFromFile`.  Ended up creating two separate lists.

In **FormCreate handler**:

```
LoadData(...)

myComboBox.Items := displayList;
```

**LoadData**

```
procedure MyForm.LoadData(
    const path: string; data: TStringList);
var index : Integer;
begin
    data.LoadFromFile(path);
    for index := 0 to data.Count - 1 do
    begin
        displayList.Add(data.ValueFromIndex[index]);
        valueList.Add(data.Names[index]);
    end;
end;
```

Whenever you need to get the selected value:

```
valueList[myComboBox.ItemIndex]
```